# How to get value of a key in NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, json, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This is the userinfo of my silent push notification. How to get value of result in objective-c?

```
{
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
        result = STOP;
        sound = "";
    };
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[Response valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"result"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE) you can dive into the nested dictionary with one method call.

```
[userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"aps.result"];
```

---

The accepted answer uses KVC's `valueForKey:`. Please be aware, that there are differences to `NSDictionary`'s own method `objectForKey:`. While the first one only takes `NSString`s as needed in the question, the second one takes any object that conforms to `NSCopying` protocol (`id<NSCopying>`). `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`,... do and it is easy to implement `NSCopying` for your own classes.

Also `NSDictionary` supports subscription. from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKeyedSubscript:):

> **`objectForKeyedSubscript:`**
>
> > Returns the value associated with a given key.
> >
> > **Discussion**
> >     This method behaves the same as `objectForKey:`

Unless you want to do something KVC-specific as in my answer, you should prefer `objectForKey:` and actually you than could write the compact code

```
id obj = userInfo[@"aps"][@"result"];
```

or if you know the class of the object (`NSString` in your example)

```
NSString *obj = userInfo[@"aps"][@"result"];
```